# uWSGI-Flask use same worker for same user

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, uwsgi

I have simple app that serve data via socket and i need stick some worker for some user. It's very similar for nginx config and called it sticky headers. But nginx doesn't know about how many workers do i have. uWSGI knows and can serve specific worker for user. But i don't know how to do it. All i need that because with multiply workers i have race condition issue

This is my config

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

socket = backend.sock
processes = 16
master = true
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
thunder-lock = true

http-websockets = true
http-socket = :1234
chmod-socket = 660
gevent = 1024
gevent-early-monkey-patch = 1
```

when i set processes `1` all works perfectly, because user served by same worker

Answer (score 0):

```
processes = 4
socket = $(PWD)/run/socket_http
socket = $(PWD)/run/socket_ws
map-socket = 0:1,2,3
map-socket = 1:4
```

This will dedicate 1 worker (the 4th) for the web socket.
In nginx you can finally do something like this:

```
location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/project/run/socket_ws;
    }
```

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/1195#issuecomment-619586400